# a combination of two foreign keys in a table, that cant be inserted multiple times

Tags: java, mysql

i got two foreign keys in a table, with a primary key.

```
Primary_key Name Foreignkey1 Foreignkey2

1           test1  2               1
2           test2  2               1    <--- how do i prevent this from entering
3           test3  2               2
```

either in java or mysql, i am displaying the data in a jtable

Comment: first select if already exists dont insert

Comment: Say what now?  You probably want to define a `UNIQUE` constraint, but your question isn't clear enough to tell you over exactly which columns...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

add `UNIQUE` constraint

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD CONSTRAINT tb_uq UNIQUE (Foreignkey1, Foreignkey2)
```

Comment: but then i run into a problem?. foreign key 1 CAN be entered multiple times, just not as a combination with foreign key 2

Comment: @hamchi no, foreign key 1 and foreign key 2 kay be entered multiple times but not both combination can be entered, example, this is valid `1 ,2`, `1, 3`, `2,3` but not `1,3` and `1,3`